# PostMessage from flutter to inappwebview

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, webview

There are many answers to this regarding the **flutter_webview** package but not a single one for **flutter_inappwebview** which we are using for a few reasons.

So is there any way to fire up a method from anywhere inside the flutter widget tree that posts/sends anything to the inappwebview for which I can listen there with JS to do something (like a console.log with the received message)?

I also opened a github issue with a little more detail and a code snippet for this although I'm not sure how frequently the dev is looking for it (he has many issues there) so I figured asking the stackoverflow community makes sense.
Here's the github issue for convenience: https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview/issues/1037

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can trigger javascript function from flutter by following these steps

1. Need to execute evaluate javascript function from flutter as below

   ```
   _webViewController.evaluateJavascript(source: """
    var event = new CustomEvent("demoJavaScriptListener", {detail: {});
   window.dispatchEvent(event); """);
   ```
2. Now in Javascript side you need write a listener as below

   ```
   window.addEventListener("demoJavaScriptListener", (event) => {
       console.log("My custom Event");
       var map= JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(event.detail));
       console.log("map",map);
   });
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Figured it out in the meantime but forgot to come back here to save everyone else the hassle. Yet it's good, new users will see your answer, so again: Thank you!